# Non-uniform feature distribution when detecting with ORB in Python

Tags: python, feature-detection, orb

I am using ORB in Python to detect features in images, in order to match a new image against a set of reference images (feature matching and homography). The new images have sub-images of interest against unknown backgrounds.

I am finding that, in some cases, many keypoints are being detected to the exclusion of keypoints of interest. Take the following example:

[image: Keypoints in sample image]

If I request the (default) 500 keypoints, none of them is in the region of interest. The writing in the image is actually 'background' to what I am trying to match, which is the large sub-image against a paler background. If I request (a lot) more keypoints, I start to get some in the region of interest, but now everything runs correspondingly more slowly: the detection and the matching.

Looking for larger features would help in this case, or features that were selected from across the entire image. What parameter(s) can I provide to cv2.ORB_create() to achieve this? Or is this not possible?

I guess I could partition the image and apply feature detection and matching to each cell but it seems like that would be far less efficient than a global approach.

I came across the notion of non-maximal suppression algorithms (https://github.com/BAILOOL/ANMS-Codes) which seems at first sight to be finding keypoints uniformly. But I must be missing something, because it operates as post-processing on the detected features.

A bigger question (I am pretty new to computer vision): are there any heuristics people have tried to help match objects somewhere inside user-taken snapshots (on mobiles) with unknown objects in the background?

Thanks for your help.